# May i have a list of games which can run fine with ubuntu and wine?

Tags: wine, games

I'd like to play games sometimes when I felt tired or bore . but I don't know which games can run fine with ubuntu and wine . so may I have list of them ?
one more thing behind this is my internet limited one . so I can't download all . so this list may help me to save the usage .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [WineHQ AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/).  Also, the meaning of the rest of your question is unclear, would you please revise it for accuracy and grammar?

Comment: Ok I've to download them right but I can't do much . I've limited usage internet connection